# WFS getFeature request no longer working

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I am trying to do a `GetFeature` with this parameters:

`POST` request:

- Url: https://inspire.navarra.es/services/CP/wfs
- Body:

```xml
<GetFeature
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" outputFormat="application/json"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <Query typeName="CP:CadastralParcel" srsName="EPSG:25830">
        <Filter
            xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <PropertyIsEqualTo matchCase="false">
                <PropertyName>nationalCadastralReference</PropertyName>
                <Literal>167090077</Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </Filter>
    </Query>
</GetFeature>
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error occurred getting features
>
> Duplicate mappingName or targetElement
> across FeatureTypeMapping instances detected. They have to be unique,
> or app-schema doesn't know which one to get.
>
> Please check your mapping
> file(s) with mappingName or targetElement of:
> http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0:CadastralParcel

What is wrong?

It was working one week ago.

Comment: did  you (or anyone else)  change anything on the server in the last week? It looks like an app-schema configuration error

Comment: @IanTurton that seems to be the problem, something in the server has ben modified. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that:

- The server has been modified.
- **The request is OK**